# Using Rename program to delete last characters before file extension

Tags: rename

1.What command do you use to delete the last 'n' characters before an extension?

13354443_Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv to 13354443_Walkinthepark.mkv

2. How to delete the first 'n' characters before and extension?

13354443_Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv to Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv

3. Also, commands to perform both.

13354443_Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv to Walkinthepark.mkv

I would like to perform this on multiple files. If possible, perform on other files in sub folders.

Comment: Please do not post additional information in an answer. Instead, use "edit" to add information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

`mmv` is good for this kind of transformation ex.

```
$ mmv -n '*_*-*.mkv' '#1_#2.mkv'
13354443_Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv -> 13354443_Walkinthepark.mkv
```

or

```
$ mmv -n '*_*-*.mkv' '#2.mkv'
13354443_Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv -> Walkinthepark.mkv
```

To do a similar thing with the Perl-based `rename` command:

```
$ rename -n 's/^(.*?)_(.*?)-(.*?)\.(.*)$/$1_$2.$4/' *.mkv
rename(13354443_Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv, 13354443_Walkinthepark.mkv)
```

Or you can use basic shell processing:

```
$ for f in *_*-*.mkv; do echo mv "$f" "${f%-*}.mkv"; done
mv 13354443_Walkinthepark-ASGDFSGDG.mkv 13354443_Walkinthepark.mkv
```